# Serialize Domain instance with service injected?

Tags: grails, serialization, dependency-injection, grails-orm, domain-object

I have a Domain object that tracks the user that created, deleted and modified it using the injected Spring Security service, `def springSecurityService`. Instances of these objects are saved in the session and in production the session is persisted to a database for session failover. The `Jetty` session storage class serializes the objects in the session but throws an exception if the session contains an object that's not serializable which the `springSecurityService` is not. Is there someway to mark the `springSecurityService` instance as ignored,  `transient` may be, but still have access to the `service`? I tried.

```
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
```

did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using,

```
transient SpringSecurityService springSecurityService
static transients = ['springSecurityService']
```

The first statement tells Java, not to serialize; whereas the second tells Grails not to persist.

**Note:** Btw, injecting service in domain class is [discouraged](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html#_domain_autowiring_disabled).

Comment: Take note that injecting a a service in a Domain class is discouraged by the Grails team as it reduces performances due to the bean injection required each time a bean instance is loaded from the DB : https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html#_domain_autowiring_disabled